# Could not load type 'StackExchange.Redis.HashEntry' from assembly 'StackExchange.Redis

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, redis, .net-4.5

I was trying to setup the RedisSessionProvider to use with my Azure website via the Nuget package that's available.

When I run my website I get the following error:

```
Could not load type 'StackExchange.Redis.HashEntry' from assembly 'StackExchange.Redis, Version=1.0.219.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out when installing a fresh copy of the RedisSessionProvider it installs a really old version of StackExchange.Redis, once I updated that it worked.

Comment: are you using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider
it has dependency on Stackexchange.redis >= 1.0.281, which is pretty latest.